# Import and sum data from multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

I'm at a loss as to do what I'm wanting.

Sheet **Main**:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TA | 30 |
| 2 | TB | 50 |
| 3 | TC | 12 |

Sheet **TA**:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | .45 |
| 2 | D | .36 |
| 3 | E | .12 |

Sheet **TB**:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | .44 |
| 2 | G | .03 |
| 3 | R | .15 |

Sheet **TC**:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | .10 |
| 2 | D | .06 |
| 3 | Z | .09 |

For each row in the sheet **main** I want to sum the result of:

```
 =query(indirect(" "&A1&"!"&"A:B"),
    "select A,B*'main!B1'")
```

which would result in:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | 36.70 |
| 2 | D | 18.72 |
| 3 | E | 3.6 |
| 4 | G | 1.50 |
| 5 | R | 7.50 |
| 6 | Z | 1.08 |

Comment: it is not clear which cells should be involved and which are the target ones, I recommend that you attach an example file

Comment: I 've linked the sheet... i'm trying to get something that will fill in the table starting at E7  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQnWWj6fk_MFSGstY1zs3fxd92K0c73mCXk9c2Y6D0D2g7ohKI341LxueDwrisK5zIQj8vY3ACDKUzv/pubhtml

Comment: This is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tBFpXI_SQFs5XHsrW3MdllIc-drCbOnxE0OZ0MELZy8/edit?usp=sharing) to your file, converted to an editable spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({
{QUERY('Table A'!A:B,"SELECT A,B * " &B5  & " WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL B * " &B5  & "''")};
{QUERY('Table B'!A:B,"SELECT A,B * " &B6  & " WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL B * " &B6  & "''")};
{QUERY('Table C'!A:B,"SELECT A,B * " &B7  & " WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL B * " &B7  & "''")}
},"SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Results', SUM(Col2) ''")
```

**Explanation**

We have three subqueries here that we stitched together using an array. Each subquery is simply multiplying the values in the B column to the specified value in the main sheet. I'm not sure if it's possible to do all this in one big query.

`WHERE A IS NOT NULL` is simply there to remove the whitespaces, and the `LABEL B` is to remove the header that comes with using an arithmetic operation.

All of these subqueries are stacked one on top of each other using the array. From here, we another query to add up the second column (here in the query is called Col2), and group it all together.

We label it to make it all pretty by removing the autogenerated header and adding 'Results'.

Comment: thanks, i guess i should have pointed it out that there are more than the three sheets and it may be that they are added to and deleted at any time (and deleted the entry from the main sheet also).  is there any way to do this without having to repeat the query command with each entry?   thanks

Comment: I don't think that's feasible with normal functions. You'll need to implement an App Script solution. An immediate thought would generate a function with all the queries, and insert it into a cell. Though that seems slow, I better idea might be to restructure your data. Add a third column which would point to which table they belong to.